# yield extended syntax and send method

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, yield

I read about `yield` extended syntax, so that if I have:

```
def numgen(N):
  for i in range(N):
    n = yield i
    if n:
      yield n
```

I can factor it:

```
def numgen(N):
  n = yield from range(N)
  if n:
    yield n
```

but I have noticed that if I do, after I have coded the second generator:

```
g = numgen(10)
next(g)
g.send(54)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in gensquare
AttributeError: 'range_iterator' object has no attribute 'send'
```

So, how is that? How can I send a value to my `numgen` generator object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`range()` is not a generator, it doesn't have a [`generator.send()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.send).

This is clearly documented in the [`yield` expression documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions):

> When `yield from <expr>` is used, it treats the supplied expression as a subiterator. All values produced by that subiterator are passed directly to the caller of the current generator’s methods. **Any values passed in with `send()`** and any exceptions passed in with `throw()` **are passed to the underlying iterator if it has the appropriate methods. If this is not the case, then `send()` will raise `AttributeError` or `TypeError`**, while `throw()` will just raise the passed in exception immediately.

Emphasis mine.

You are trying to send a value to the `range()` iterator, but it has no `.send()` method.

`range()` is *just a sequence*, not a generator object; you can create multiple iterators for it, you can test if a number is a member of the sequence, ask it for its length, etc.

Note that your 'refactoring' is not the same thing at all; in your original `n` is assigned anything you send in through `generator.send()`; in your second version `yield from` returns the `value` attribute of the `StopIteration` exception raised when the sub-iterator ends. If the sub-iterator is a generator itself, you can set that value either by manually raising `StopIteration(value)` or by using a `return` statement. `yield from` cannot return the value sent in with `generator.send()` because such values would be passed on to the sub-generator instead.

Again, from the documentation:

> When the underlying iterator is complete, the value attribute of the raised `StopIteration` instance becomes the value of the yield expression. It can be either set explicitly when raising `StopIteration`, or automatically when the sub-iterator is a generator (by returning a value from the sub-generator).

So your first version is set up to receive `N` messages, yielding both the `i` `for` target and any sent value is true-thy, while the other passes on any sent messages to a degelated-to generator, then would yield just the `StopIteration` value if it is true-thy *once*, after the delegated-to iterator is done.

Comment: I don't understand, I just tried it in python3.4 and it works, without parenthesis

Comment: @antox: ah, yes, `yield from` calls `iter()` on the object, my mistake.

Comment: '[...] while throw() will just raise the passed in exception immediately.' will the exception be thrown in the generator obejct? on in the place where the `throw()` was called?

Comment: @antox: `.throw()` raises the exception where the generator is paused. In this case, at the `yield from` line.

Comment: "Any values passed in with send() [...] are passed to the underlying iterator if it has the appropriate methods." which methods should an iterator define to get those values?

Comment: @antox: a **generator** defines those methods. See the [*Generator-iterator methods* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-iterator-methods).

Comment: @MartijinPieters yet some questions, is it possibile, using a subiterator, manipulate the values returned? I mean do something like this `yield from (range(N))**2` (I know the syntax is not correct, but I would only explain what I mean)

Comment: @antox: no, because you are just passing on the values. The current generator *steps aside* to delegate iteration.

Comment: so if the `yield from` is used there is no way to `send` a value to the delegating generator?

Comment: @antox: no, `yield from` passes on the 'message' on to the sub-generator. That's kind of the point of the syntax.